# How to prove an irrational exponential number with its exponent divisors also leading to irrational exponential numbers

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, exponentiation, irrational-numbers

If $x^n$ is irrational for some $n ∈ N$, how do I prove that $x^d$ is irrational for any divisor $d$ of $n$?

I'm thinking of using a proof of contradiction for something like this. I know how to prove just a normal base number irrational, by equaling it to $a/b$ doing proof by contradiction, but having an exponent factored into it makes it a but confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x^d$ is rational. Then $(x^d)^c=x^{dc}=x^n$ (where $dc=n$, since $d\mid n$) must also be rational, which is a contradiction. Thus $x^d$ is irrational.

Comment: This assumes a rational number times a number is rational. shouldn't that be proved as well?

Comment: @user3427042 I omitted the proof, since it's "nearly trivial": $(p/q)^n=p^n/q^n$

Comment: but a rational number times an irrational number is an irrational number, what you showed is just the same rational number times itself

Comment: @user3427042 Irrelevant. I assumed $x^d$ was rational, exponentiated it (assuming rationality) and arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: oh ok, I see now, thanks